# Remove from local storage task which was clicked

Tags: javascript, dom, local-storage

I need to remove task from local storage. I'm already write function for delete task from DOM but I don't have any ideas how to remove exactly that object from local storage for save changes. As i understand, need to get parse data from local storage and loop for keys and delete item which have same "title" but if I remove from local storage I cannot iterate.

```
<h1 class="text-center mt-5 mb-5">TODO LIST</h1>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">
    <form id="todoForm">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label">Task title</label>
        <input type="text" required name="title" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label  class="form-label">Task body</label>
        <textarea name="description" required class="form-control" placeholder="Task body" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Task!</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col-8">
    <div class="row" id="todoItems">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
    const toDoList = {
    selector: null,
    form: null,
    containerSelector: null,
    container: null,
    init (selector, container) {
        if(typeof selector === "string" || selector.trim() !== "") {
            this.selector = selector;
        }
        if(typeof container === "string" || container.trim() !== "") {
            this.containerSelector = container;
        }
        this.getForm();
        this.getHTMLElement();
    },
    getForm () {
        let formElement = document.querySelector(this.selector);
        this.form = formElement;
        formElement.addEventListener("submit", event => {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            const data = {};
            formElement.querySelectorAll("input, textarea")
                .forEach((item) => {
                    data[item.name] = item.value;
                    //data.Id = Math.random().toString(16).slice(2);
                })
            const saveData = this.saveData(data);
            this.renderItem(saveData);
        })
    },

    getHTMLElement() {
        const todoContainer = document.querySelector(this.containerSelector);
        this.container = todoContainer;
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", event => {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            const toDo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.selector));
            if(!toDo) return "Error!";
            toDo.map(todoItem => {
                this.renderItem(todoItem);
            })
        })
    },

    saveData(data) {
        let dataFromStore = localStorage.getItem(this.selector);
        if(!dataFromStore) {
            const array = [];
            array.push(data);
            localStorage.setItem(this.selector, JSON.stringify(array));
        }
        if(dataFromStore) {
            dataFromStore = JSON.parse(dataFromStore);
            dataFromStore.push(data);
            localStorage.setItem(this.selector, JSON.stringify(dataFromStore));
        }
        return data;
    },

    renderItem(data) {
        const title = data.title;
        const description = data.description;
        const wrapper = document.createElement("div");
        wrapper.classList.add("col-4");
        wrapper.innerHTML = `<div class="taskWrapper">
            <div class="taskHeading">${title}</div>
            <div class="taskDescription">${description}</div>
            <button class="delBtn" data-del="delete">Delete</button>
            </div>`;
        this.container.appendChild(wrapper);
    },

    deleteItem() {
        document.addEventListener('click', e => {
            let targetBtn = e.target.getAttribute("data-del");
            if(targetBtn === "delete") {
                // Delete from dom
                let titleTsk = e.target.parentNode.firstElementChild;
                e.target.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
                // ============== //
                let nameOfTask = titleTsk.innerHTML;
                let findTsk = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("#todoForm"));
                console.log(findTsk);
            }
        })
    }
}
toDoList.init("#todoForm", "#todoItems");
toDoList.deleteItem();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

```
        deleteItem() {
        document.addEventListener('click', e => {
            const targetBtn = e.target.getAttribute("data-del");
            if(targetBtn === "delete") {
                const titleTsk = e.target.parentNode.firstElementChild;
                e.target.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
                const nameOfTask = titleTsk.innerHTML;
                const findTsk = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("#todoForm"));
                const indexOfObject = findTsk.findIndex(object => {
                    return object.title === nameOfTask;
                });
                findTsk.splice(indexOfObject, 1);
                localStorage.setItem(this.selector, JSON.stringify(findTsk));
            }
        });
    }
```